# Excel Macro not finding next empty row, just overwriting last one

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel spreadsheet with macro's which enters details from form to next empty row. For some reason today it is just over writing the last empty row.

I cant figure out why. Here is snippet of code.

```
'1. Find first empty row in appropriate sheet
        If optActivity = True Then
            Activity.Activate
            RowNum = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("Activity_Clubs")) + 1
        ElseIf optEMP = True Then
            EMP.Activate
            RowNum = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("EMP_Clubs")) + 1
    End If
```

Them EMP spreadsheet is working fine, just not the activity one. Anyone have idea, could the activity one be at its max?

Answer: This has seems to solve the problem
changing this line

```
RowNum = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("Activity_Clubs")) + 1
```

to this

```
RowNum = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("Activity_Clubs")) + 2
```

first line worked all year, until today. Really strange.

Comment: ` today it is just over writing the last empty row` So the code was working fine, and even though code is NOT changed results ARE chnaged?? So, what makes you think it is an issue with your code? there is a chance that a row was cleared

Comment: You should try fully qualifying your ranges, e.g., `Activity.Range(...)`, and using a different method to find the last row, e.g., `Activity.Range("A" & Activity.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: I ve done numerous tests, and it just ends up over writing the last line of the excel.

Comment: Hey @DougGlancy What will go in the Range(..)?

Comment: The same thing you had in it. The important part is that you specify what worksheet the `Range` is in. user2140261's answer is a more complete explanation.

Comment: Is [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) what you are trying?

Comment: Get sure your named ranges (`Activity_Clubs` and `EMP_Clubs`) are big enough to fit all data. Also, that you have no gaps in then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the last Empty Row in a Column one of the best methods would be to use the following:

```
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
```

For your use try this

```
'1. Find first empty row in appropriate sheet
        If optActivity = True Then
            RowNum = Activity.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ElseIf optEMP = True Then
            RowNum = EMP.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If
```

Comment: hey, did that. THen next line i got error on this line
    a. General - same for every type of grant
        Range("Processing_Date").Offset(RowNum).Value = Date

Comment: Error is "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed.

Comment: You need to add the Worksheet names to the beginning of all your range calls, especially now that I removed the Activate methods.

Comment: Something like sheets("SheetName").range("Processing_Date").offset(RowNum).value=Date

Comment: @SathishKothandam No A is the column that has the data in it, use the column values instead of the named ranges.